# Вопрос про события. (vue js, jquery)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события

В общем имеется следующий js код (vue). Переделывал этот же код на jquery, вопрос тот же. Когда ввожу слово, например: Hello. В консоли, предыдущий символ появляется только после нажатия следующего, хотя в поле "Введенные слова все хорошо, как жмешь, сразу же появляется символ. Пытался событие поменять на keyup, в этом случае работает нормально и там и там, но если быстро печатать, почему-то keyup теряет некоторые символы. С keydown нет таких проблем, но здесь проблема в том, что я указал выше. Как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо

```js
           var example1 = new Vue({
                el: '#getWord',
                data: {
                    word: '',
                    words: [],
                    counter: 4
                },
                methods:{
                    getWordFromInput: function (event){                 

                        if(this.counter >= 0){
                          console.log("Введенные слова: " + this.words.join(","));
                            return;
                        }

                        console.log("Текущее слово: " + this.word);
                    },
                     spaceDown: function (value){
                            this.words.push(this.word);
                            this.word = '';
                            event.preventDefault();
                            this.counter--;
                            
                    }
                }
            });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test vue</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        
        <div id="getWord">
            <input v-model="word" @keydown = "getWordFromInput" @keydown.space = "spaceDown" placeholder="отредактируй меня">
            <p>Введенное слово: {{ word }}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: забудьте про keyup, используйте input

Comment: У меня задача не в том, чтобы получить все содержимое в input целиком, это часть задача. Также задача взять каждый отдельный символ и он должен быть текущим, а не предыдущим как у меня сейчас. По событию нажатия на клавишу в консоли хочу выводить текущее слово: например нажал букву H, оно появилось в консоли, затем e, и так далее. Сейчас происходит какая-то задержка символа по какой причине неясно.

Comment: да зачем вам эти клавиши ? ну если уж очень нужен вводимый символ - сравнивайте с предыдущей строкой, просто input это именно событие обновления инпута, т.е.  и paste и  drag&drop строки из другого приложения и почти всё (кроме обновления чрез .val= в js) я к чему - keyup  слишком низкоуровневое, как на ассемблере звуковую карту программировать

Comment: Ну с ассемблером вы явно перегнули). Ладно, тогда скажите как я могу получить текущее введенное слово в консоли?) без событий) То есть как мне вызвать метод getWordFromInput без событий на текущий момент времени)

Comment: в каком смысле без событий ?  Без событий никак, таймер тоже событие.
получить ввод так
```input.addEventListener('input', event => console.log(event.target.val)``` ?

Comment: Что-то про addEventListener я совсем не подумал, ну я пока только учусь мне простительно) Спасибо огромное это помогло) Как тут +100500 к репутации поставить?)